# Selecting everything between two heading anchor tags

Tags: python, css, beautifulsoup

I am currently attempting to scrape a webpage for a small project. However, when attempting to select everything between two headings I've run into a problem. Here is an example of one of the headings I am trying to select:

```
<h2><a class="autolink" href="/compendium/dnd5e/Social%20Interaction#h-Long%20Rest">Long Rest</a></h2>
```

Found in: https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Rules:Resting/#h-Resting

And here is the code I have so far:

```
 els = soup.select("h2:has(a:contains('Short Rest')) ~ *:has(~ h2:has(a:contains('Long Rest')))")
```

However, using this returns a list of all the tags used and their, not the text as I thought. The desired output would be all the HTML between h2 'Short Rest' and h2 'Long Rest', so essentially the text describing a short rest.

The reason I am not using a simpler `tag.next_sibling` method is that there is a lot of untagged text on this webpage, which that method skips over.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've been stuck on this for a while now.

Comment: Did you want an extra ) as in contains('Short Rest'))  If you provide the link and indicate the desired result we can test

Comment: @QHarr Ah, apologies for the typo there, that solves the error problem but still does not return the desired result - I will update the question to demonstrate that.

Comment: I think you actually might need next_sibling potentially as that text is sitting under a higher parent div and will be missed by your current general sibling combinator.

Comment: @QHarr though as stated in the question, this skips the untagged text as they are not found through the use of next_sibling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this should do the trick:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from bs4 import NavigableString
soup = bs(req.text,'lxml')
final_text = []
for item in soup.find("h2",text="Short Rest").next_siblings:
    if item.name=="h2":
        break
    if isinstance(item, NavigableString):        
        final_text.extend(item)
    else:
        final_text.extend(item.stripped_strings)

print("".join(final_text))
```

Output:

> A Short Rest is a period of downtime, at least 1 hour long, during
> which a character does nothing more strenuous than eating, drinking,
> reading, and tending to wounds.A character can spend one or more Hit
> Dice at the end of a Short Rest, up to the character’s maximum number
> of Hit Dice, which is equal to the character’s level. For each Hit Die
> spent in this way, the player rolls the die and adds the character’s
> Constitution modifier to it. The character regains Hit Points equal to
> the total. The player can decide to spend an additional Hit Die after
> each roll. A character regains some spent Hit Dice upon finishing a
> Long Rest, as explained below.

Comment: Nice use of .extend!